# 'TreeModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class

Tags: angular, angular-tree-component

I just literally follow the step by step here in this [documentation](https://angular2-tree.readme.io/docs/getting-started#slack-community) but for some reason im having this error when i try to import angular-tree-component in app.module.ts [eror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5ZcB.png)

i just follow the documentation written here https://angular2-tree.readme.io/docs/getting-started#slack-community.

Comment: Read the error: "ThreeModule is **not** compatible with Angular Ivy, check if a **newer** version...".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular v16 has dropped the support for non-ivy libraries.

[This library](https://github.com/CirclonGroup/angular-tree-component/blob/master/tsconfig.json) choose to not enable ivy by default.

So you won't be able to use it in a v16 project !

Answer (score 1):

The original library does not enable ivy by default and no one knows whether they change it in the near future.

You can use `@bugsplat/angular-tree-component` which is a fork of `angular-tree-component` which was original an upgrade to Angular 13, but it seems to work fine with 16 as well.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@bugsplat/angular-tree-component

The other option is this one:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ali-hm/angular-tree-component